# How do I get the value from a GWT SelectElement?

Tags: gwt

I am trying to get the value of a SelectElement using the getValue() method of that class. However, when I debug and watch what's happening, the value is always null. I am able to confirm that the SelectElement contains the expected HTML node when debugging and that one of the options contained within has the selected attribute.

Here is the code that finds the select element in the DOM and tries reading the value:

```
SelectElement e = (SelectElement) DOM.getElementById( "sel-" + transaction.getId().toString() ).cast(); 
Boolean isAcknowledged = Enums.TransactionType.ACKNOWLEDGED.equals( e.getValue() );
```

As I said above, calling the e.getValue() method does not return a value but when I watch what is contained in e, I see the expected HTML node with one of the options set as selected.

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel-88024">
   <option value="CONSUMED" selected="">Used</option>
   <option value="ACKNOWLEDGED">Received</option>
</select>
```

But there is never a value in getValue(). Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is not related to GWT. Could it be that `Enums.TransactionType` is a real Java-Enum and you have to use `Enums.TransactionType.ACKNOWLEDGED.name().equals(e.getValue())`?

Comment: You're probably right but, sadly, e.getValue() still doesn't contain a value. :(

Comment: I tried exactly your sample and it works like a charm. Is your transactionid wrong?

Comment: Well, DOM.getElementById() finds the node in the HTML and returns what I'm expecting so I'm not sure how my transactionId could be wrong. If that were wrong, it wouldn't find the element in the HTML, right?

Comment: I think I may have found the problem. The element that is returned as "e" contains the HTML as it is originally rendered, not the current state of the HTML. I must be using a reference to the element instead of the element itself. Meaning, it's not attached to the DOM like I thought it was. :|